# Pythonでexec文字列の中にプログラムを書くとNameErrorになる

Tags: python3

あけましておめでとうございます。本年もよろしくお願いします。
Python3で以下のようなコードを実行したところ、エラーが発生しました。
実験の趣旨はexecにプログラムを文字列で渡すことです。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# hash_exec_test.py

def exec_test(s):
    exec(s)

exec_test ('''
book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}
print("↓↓One-Values↓↓")
print(book["Apple"])
print()
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")
print(keys)
print()
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Values↓↓")
print(values)
''')
```

実行結果は以下のとおりです。

```
$ ./hash_exec_test.py
↓↓One-Values↓↓
[120, 15]

↓↓All-Keys↓↓
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hash_exec_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    ''')
  File "./hash_exec_test.py", line 5, in exec_test
    exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'book' is not defined
```

bookという名前が定義されていない、と言われています。
しかし、上ではbook["Apple"]という検索が成功していますし、その後でキーを取り出すことはできているのに、最後に値を取り出そうとすると成功しない理由が分かりません。

ちなみに、関数exec_testを介さずに、execに文字列を渡してみます。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# hash_exec_test.py

exec ('''
book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}
print("↓↓One-Values↓↓")
print(book["Apple"])
print()
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")
print(keys)
print()
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Values↓↓")
print(values)
''')
```

これだとうまくいきます。

```
$ ./hash_exec_test.py
↓↓One-Values↓↓
[120, 15]

↓↓All-Keys↓↓
['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple']

↓↓All-Values↓↓
[[60, 71], [95, 32], [120, 15]]
```

なお、ディクショナリ型bookをグローバル変数にしてみます。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# hash_exec_test.py

def exec_test(s):
    exec(s)

book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}

exec_test ('''
print("↓↓One-Values↓↓")
print(book["Apple"])
print()
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")
print(keys)
print()
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Values↓↓")
print(values)
''')
```

これでも、うまくいきます。

```
$ ./hash_exec_test.py
↓↓One-Values↓↓
[120, 15]

↓↓All-Keys↓↓
['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']

↓↓All-Values↓↓
[[95, 32], [120, 15], [60, 71]]
```

なぜ一番上のケースで、値のリストを得ようとするところだけNameErrorになるのでしょうか。
ご教示願います。
ちなみに環境は以下のとおりです。

```
$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-AHPUUO5 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
```

（2017-01-02 11:51 追記）
ローカル変数の定義状況を示すためにprint(locals())を加えてみました。

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# hash_exec_test.py
def exec_test(s):
    exec(s)

exec_test ('''
book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}
print("locals")
print(locals())
print()
print("One-Values:")
print(book["Apple"])
print()
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("All-Keys")
print(keys)
print()
print("locals in the list comprehension")
values = [locals() for x in list(book.keys())]
print(values)
print("All-Values")
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("All-Values")
print(values)
''')
```

実行結果は以下のとおりです。

```
$ ./hash_exec_test.py
locals
{'s': '\nbook = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}\nprint("locals")\nprint(locals())\nprint()\nprint("One-Values:")\nprint(book["Apple"])\nprint()\nkeys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]\nprint("All-Keys")\nprint(keys)\nprint()\nprint("locals in the list comprehension")\nvalues = [locals() for x in list(book.keys())]\nprint(values)\nprint("All-Values")\nvalues = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]\nprint("All-Values")\nprint(values)\n', 'book': {'Banana': [60, 71], 'Orange': [95, 32], 'Apple': [120, 15]}}

One-Values:
[120, 15]

All-Keys
['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple']

locals in the list comprehension
[{'x': 'Apple', '.0': <list_iterator object at 0x7f871a502470>}, {'x': 'Apple', '.0': <list_iterator object at 0x7f871a502470>}, {'x': 'Apple', '.0': <list_iterator object at 0x7f871a502470>}]
All-Values
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hash_exec_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    ''')
  File "./hash_exec_test.py", line 4, in exec_test
    exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'book' is not defined
```

リスト内包表記の中ではローカル変数bookが定義されていません。
これが原因なのでしょう。
ではなぜ

```
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
```

は正しく動いたかというと、book.keys()は<list_iterator object at 0x7f871a502470>を介して（？）bookにアクセスできていたということでしょうか。

Comment: `book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}` の後に `print(globals()["book"])` を追加してみると分かるかと思いますが、`exec_test` 関数内で `exec` を実行する場合には `KeyError` になります。一方、トップレベルで `exec` を実行する場合にはエラーになりません。詳しい解説は stackoverflow.com(本家)にあるかと思いますので割愛して、解決策の一つとしては `exec(s)` を `exec(s, {}, {'book': {}})` に変更して `book = {"Apple":[120,15], ...}` の直前に `global book` を追加すると良いかと。

Comment: metropolis様、回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: metropolis様、回答ありがとうございました。
print(globals()["book"]) を追加してもエラーになること、確認しました。
stackoverflow.com(本家)を「KeyError exec」で検索しましたが私のケースに尋ねあたりませんでした。
global book を追加すると動作すること、確認しました。
しかしながら、もともとの疑問の理由はいまだ分かりません。
もしご教示くださる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Comment: これですかね https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904274/globals-and-locals-in-python-exec 。コメント中のリンク先 https://bugs.python.org/issue991196 がわかりやすいですが、コードがトップレベルで実行されるかどうかがポイントだそうです。

Comment: dokubeko様もありがとうございます！
以下の回答を見て半分くらい分かってきました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578573/behavior-of-python-exec-differs-depending-on-the-where-it-is-called-from

私の最初のコードで、bookを定義した直下で`print(global())`と書いてもbookは印字されませんが、二番目のコード（execをトップレベルで実行しているコードで同じように書くと、bookが表示されます。

つまり、exec関数をトップレベルで実行すると、文字列の中で定義されている変数はグローバル変数になるが、関数の中で実行すると、そうならないために、参照できない、ということでしょうか。

残りの半分わからないのは、`print(book["Apple"])`や`keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]`のようなコードは、それでもbookにアクセスできるのに、`values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]`だけが怒られるということです。。

Comment: ちなみにPython2だとエラーになりません。リスト内包表記がPython3だと別スコープになることに関係があると思います。でもそれだけではモジュールレベルの時と関数を介した時の挙動の差が説明できないですね。

Comment: Kenji Noguchi様、ありがとうございます！
そうなんです、関数を介すると参照できるんですよね。。
Python2だとエラーにならないことも確認しました。

Comment: list comprehension で別スコープになるのは output expression 部のみなのです。つまり、`[book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]` は `list(map(lambda x: book[x], list(book.keys())))` と同値です。トップレベルでは globals() と locals() の結果は一致するのでエラーにはなりません。